# sql remove duplicates value from rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables.

payment_process, process, and booking_extras.

So when anyone book an extra I add in all 3 tables data. When I have in every table 2 rows then if I select I get 6 rows. x3 Why and how can I solve it ?

```
        SELECT
        DISTINCT

        p.booking_id AS PBID,
        p.process_id AS PID,
        p.payment_method,
        p.price,
        p.paid,
        p.created_at,

        be.km,
        be.km_50,
        be.km_100,
        be.km_200,
        be.km_300,
        be.km_500,
        be.to_date,

        pc.text,
        pc.is_owner

        FROM process pc

        INNER JOIN payment_process p
        ON p.process_id = pc.id

        LEFT OUTER JOIN booking_extras be
        ON be.booking_id = p.booking_id

        WHERE pc.booking_id = $1 LIMIT 100;
```

Rows

```
[
  {
    pbid: 2,
    pid: 5,
    payment_method: '100% Bar vor Ort',
    price: 300,
    paid: 0,
    created_at: 2023-03-23T16:40:09.271Z,
    km: null,
    km_50: 1,
    km_100: null,
    km_200: null,
    km_300: null,
    km_500: null,
    to_date: null,
    text: 'Buchung',
    is_owner: 1
  },
  {
    pbid: 2,
    pid: 5,
    payment_method: '100% Bar vor Ort',
    price: 300,
    paid: 0,
    created_at: 2023-03-23T16:40:09.271Z,
    km: null,
    km_50: null,
    km_100: null,
    km_200: 1,
    km_300: null,
    km_500: null,
    to_date: null,
    text: 'Buchung',
    is_owner: 1
  },
  {
    pbid: 2,
    pid: 6,
    payment_method: '100% Bar vor Ort',
    price: 25,
    paid: 0,
    created_at: 2023-03-23T16:37:38.811Z,
    km: null,
    km_50: 1,
    km_100: null,
    km_200: null,
    km_300: null,
    km_500: null,
    to_date: null,
    text: 'Buchung',
    is_owner: 1
  },
  {
    pbid: 2,
    pid: 6,
    payment_method: '100% Bar vor Ort',
    price: 25,
    paid: 0,
    created_at: 2023-03-23T16:37:38.811Z,
    km: null,
    km_50: null,
    km_100: null,
    km_200: 1,
    km_300: null,
    km_500: null,
    to_date: null,
    text: 'Buchung',
    is_owner: 1
  },
  {
    pbid: 2,
    pid: 7,
    payment_method: '100% Bar vor Ort',
    price: 100,
    paid: 0,
    created_at: 2023-03-23T16:43:02.549Z,
    km: null,
    km_50: 1,
    km_100: null,
    km_200: null,
    km_300: null,
    km_500: null,
    to_date: null,
    text: 'Buchung',
    is_owner: 1
  },
  {
    pbid: 2,
    pid: 7,
    payment_method: '100% Bar vor Ort',
    price: 100,
    paid: 0,
    created_at: 2023-03-23T16:43:02.549Z,
    km: null,
    km_50: null,
    km_100: null,
    km_200: 1,
    km_300: null,
    km_500: null,
    to_date: null,
    text: 'Buchung',
    is_owner: 1
  }
]
```

I have solve it like this but Idk if the query has performance problems or is bad

```
        SELECT

        pc.text,
        pc.is_owner,

        payment_process.booking_id, payment_process.process_id, payment_process.price, payment_process.paid, payment_process.payment_method, payment_process.created_at,

        booking_extras.km,
        booking_extras.km_50,
        booking_extras.km_100,
        booking_extras.km_200,
        booking_extras.km_300,
        booking_extras.km_500,
        booking_extras.to_date

        FROM process pc

        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT 
            payment_process.booking_id, 
            payment_process.process_id, 
            payment_process.price,
            payment_process.paid,
            payment_process.payment_method,
            payment_process.created_at
          FROM payment_process
           GROUP BY payment_process.booking_id, payment_process.process_id, payment_process.price, payment_process.paid, payment_process.payment_method, payment_process.created_at
        ) payment_process ON payment_process.process_id = pc.id

        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT 
            booking_extras.id, 
            booking_extras.km, 
            booking_extras.km_50,
            booking_extras.km_100,
            booking_extras.km_200,
            booking_extras.km_300,
            booking_extras.km_500,
            booking_extras.to_date
            
            FROM booking_extras
             GROUP BY 
             booking_extras.id, 
             booking_extras.km, 
             booking_extras.km_50,
             booking_extras.km_100,
             booking_extras.km_200,
             booking_extras.km_300,
             booking_extras.km_500,
             booking_extras.to_date
             
        ) booking_extras ON pc.booking_extras_id = booking_extras.id

        WHERE pc.booking_id = $1 GROUP BY
         pc.id, pc.text, pc.is_owner,
          payment_process.booking_id, payment_process.process_id, payment_process.price, payment_process.paid, payment_process.payment_method, payment_process.created_at,
          booking_extras.km,
          booking_extras.km_50,
          booking_extras.km_100,
          booking_extras.km_200,
          booking_extras.km_300,
          booking_extras.km_500,
          booking_extras.to_date
          
        LIMIT 50;
```

I need help

Maybe I have 2 rows in three table then I get 6x rows, maybe 2x 3tables so how can I remove duplicate values

Comment: All the raws shown are different. What is the desired output?

Comment: If you want one row from your 2 examples by using DISTINCT your values are different.  This is NULL in 2nd but populated in first:   km_50: 1,  So you would get 2 rows returned.